# Sanitze path for Windows command line (cmd.exe)

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I'd like to start a program from the Windows command line (cmd.exe) with a command like this: "myProg.exe [path]" e.g.  "myProg.exe c:\files\file.txt"  but the path ist defined by a user and has to be checked with a sort of algorithm. (no manuell check) I have to prevent the user from "escaping" from the command and running his own commands.

So how can I sanitize a path to be sure that it can't containe other commands in Windows? The sanitize can be done in a self written program like a java program

Comment: In Java: let's say you got a "path" String variable - you can do create a new File object and call isFile() on it. Something like this: new File(path).isFile()

Comment: [if exist](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: Is the "algorithm" to check a file known? What is it? Can you provide and example of the "escaping" a user could do?

Answer (score 0):

[ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) replaced Runtime.exec many years ago.  ProcessBuilder passes arguments directly to a process;  since you don’t build a command string yourself, there is no possibility of inadvertently executing a second command.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("myProg.exe", userPath);
builder.inheritIO();
Process process = builder.start();
```